# Calling a webservice method asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I need to call the `Register()` method on a Web service asynchronously (using C#). The implementation of the actual `Register` method in the Web service does not return any value. But it throws an exception if the method fails. Given this, does the following code look ok please?

```
public void RegisterProduct(string productName)
{
    await RegisterProductAsync();
}


private async static Task RegisterProductAsync(string productName)
{
    try
    { 
         await myWebService.Register(productName);   
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you asking for the code review? Better place for that would be https://codereview.stackexchange.com. If you are facing any issue with this code, please explain.

Comment: (1) Your `async` method should return a `Task`, not `void`.  (2) The logging should probably include the actual exception that was caught.  (3) Why doesn't the calling method await the operation?  "fire and forget" has a nasty tendency to be, well, forgotten.  Don't obscure asynchronous operations, require the calling code to know about them.

Answer (score 0):

I will probably write the following code:

```
    private async static Task<int> RegisterProductAsync(string productName)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => myWebService.Register(productName));
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException();
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public async Task<int> RegisterProduct(string productName)
    {
        var result = await RegisterProductAsync(productName);
        return result;
    }
```

Following the rule 'async' all the way.

Comment: Thanks Joe.Sorry, I didnt mention earlier but RegisterProduct() method is part of an interface which my class is implementing.And in the interface, that method' signature has void and not Task<int>.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the service, I guess you know a proxy file gets generated.

In the proxy file you can make a note of associated `async` function, which returns `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<xxxxxx>` for return values.

So in your case for `Register`, you can make a note of function `RegisterAsync(string)` in the proxy file.

You can invoke that function (in your case: `RegisterAsync(string`)) for asynchronous call.

```
myWebService.RegisterAsync(productName);
```